# opencl - Kernel limitations

Tags: opencl

At work I write batches that can take minutes or even hours to run. They usually retrieve data (long database or web service queries), call analytics (dlls) function that compute, and output the results.

At first, I thought OpenCL could help reduce the run time drastically, but I'm not sure anymore as it seems a Kernel cannot use dlls, nor even open a simple text file.

Is that correct?

More generally, could OpenCl help us even though we don't really make calculations ourselves (no matrix multiplication etc.)?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right. OpenCL code cannot use DLL code and cannot make operating system calls. OpenCL is good for running hundreds or thousands of threads through a stand-alone algorithm in lock step.

Comment: Agreed. OpenCL is not going to help you if you are mostly doing disk I/O or calling someone else's DLLs. OpenCL (or any of the other GPGPU frameworks) is targeted for problem sets that are compute- or memory-bound.